# Google Analytics V4 - bool configuration name not recognized

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm seeing this in Logcat:

```
W/GAV4: String xml configuration name not recognized:  ga_trackingId
W/GAV4: Bool xml configuration name not recognized:  ga_autoActivityTracking
W/GAV4: Bool configuration name not recognized:  ga_reportUncaughtExceptions
```

In Manifest.xml I have:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
        android:resource="@xml/track" />
```

In App.java:

```
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.track);
```

In track.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-****</string>
    <string name="ga_logLevel">error</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>
    <integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">120</integer>
</resources>
```

Are the boolean parameters in the configuration file ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove metadata from manifest and delete `track.xml` file. Instead configure it from code like this:

```
final String trackingId = MyApplication.DEBUG ? AnalyticsManager.GA_TRACKING_ID_DEBUG
                    : AnalyticsManager.GA_TRACKING_ID_PROD;
    final int versionCode = BuildConfigHelper.VERSION_CODE;
    this.mDefaultTracker = analytics.newTracker(trackingId);
    this.mDefaultTracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    this.mDefaultTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(false);
    this.mDefaultTracker.enableExceptionReporting(false);
    this.mDefaultTracker.setSessionTimeout(300);
    this.mDefaultTracker.set("&av", String.valueOf(versionCode));
```